# how can I avoid this function modifies the class of my initial object

Tags: r, function, data.table

As the title says,

```
# install.packages(c("dplyr"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
tbl <- tibble(id = rep(0:1, c(7, 10)),
             grp = rep(c(0,1,0,1,2), c(3,4,2,5,3)),
             LET = rep(c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'), c(1,4, 3, 3, 4, 2)))

# install.packages(c("data.table"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(data.table) 
class(tbl)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
dt_by_akrun  <- function(x) {foo <- x; setDT(foo)[, grp_LET := LET[1], .(id, grp)]; as_tibble(foo)}
invisible(dt_by_akrun(tbl))
class(tbl)
#> [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning `foo <-x`, we can assign it to `copy(x)`

```
dt_by_akrun  <- function(x) {foo <- copy(x)
                  setDT(foo)[, grp_LET := LET[1], .(id, grp)]
                   as_tibble(foo)
               }
invisible(dt_by_akrun(tbl))
class(tbl)
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Comment: Thanks, I sued it to update [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934574/tidyr-group-by-mutatefoo-fill) with a micro benchmark comparison. Please feel free to optimize any of the functions.

Comment: @EricFail  Thanks for the comments.  I checked you microbenchmark.  Is it based on a larger dataset?  If it is not, then the comparison may not be accurate because when the dataset size increases, you will find the difference in efficiency of the data.table solution

Comment: It's based on the _dummy_ data I provided. I might update it if I get the time to run it on my production data.

Comment: @EricFail If you run on production data, you would find the difference.  I would run on at least 1e6 or greater than that number of rows (assuming that you have only fewer number of columns

Comment: @Eric You could make a large reproducible example for a benchmark (eg, write example data generation as a function of the number of rows). Btw, akrun's approach only loses to tidyverse in your benchmark because of the two copies being taken -- the core operation should be faster with data.table (or dtplyr, maybe).

Comment: @Frank, please feel free to add to the benchmark data. I would be very interested to learn how how to optimize either functions or other.